# Image moves based on screen size

Tags: html, css

As you guys can [see here](http://www.501sandycove.com/page.php?page_id=5) the "new" image to the right of BOAT moves if the screen becomes bigger or larger or smaller. I need it to stop moving and stay next to BOAT. Here's the html with inline CSS for it.

```
 <li>
   <img src="/images/new_sandycove.png" style="margin-top: -29px; position: absolute; margin-left: 965px; z-index: 1;">
         </li>
```

Comment: Help you out with what? You want the image to stop moving? You want it to move with the rest of the elements?

Comment: I need it to stop moving and stay next to BOAT

Comment: I don't agree that it was unclear. OP just didn't understand the concepts of absolute positioning well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<img>` is absolutely positioned. You need to make sure that the encompassing parent `<li>` has `position: relative;` set.

When elements have `position: absolute;`, it's positioned absolutely to the nearest parent that explicitly has the `position` CSS set, and if there isn't any, then it's to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you want it?
The simple answer is to take out the style tag altogether, then that will probably put it alongside the other items in that line.
Alternatively you could move it above the UL tag, remove the LI tags from it, and use style="float: right;" - that might put it where you want it, depending if you have set a width on your container.